# Instasharper does not return Likers and Tags list

Tags: c#, instagram-api

I have this piece of code in C# using [InstaSharper](https://github.com/a-legotin/InstaSharper) to return information of a media id from Instagram.

```
public async Task<UserSessionData> SignIn(string userName, string password)
        {
            userSessionData = new UserSessionData();
            userSessionData.UserName = "username";
            userSessionData.Password = "password";
            api = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder()
                .SetUser(userSessionData)
                .Build();
            var loginRequest = await api.LoginAsync();
            if (loginRequest.Succeeded && api.IsUserAuthenticated)
            {
                IResult<InstaUser> userSearch = await api.GetUserAsync(userName);
                IResult<InstaMediaList> media = await api.GetUserMediaAsync(userName, PaginationParameters.MaxPagesToLoad(1));
                IResult<InstaMedia> mediaInfo =  await api.GetMediaByIdAsync("1924613027431050955");
                return userSessionData;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

**GetMediaByIdAsync** method correctly returns data about the requested media but the Likers and Tags collection is empty. Is there any way to include those data?

Comment: I would personally recommend you use this  https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp ive used it myself a few times in the past and it gets regular updates

Comment: Tried it, again the same result. As the InstagramApiSharp says itself, it is based on InstaSharper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue, I found the solution.
Try using this code:

```
var posts = await api.GetUserMediaAsync("username", PaginationParameters.MaxPagesToLoad(Int32.MaxValue)); // If you want to load all of the posts. If not, replace the "Int32.MaxValue" with the amount of posts you want to load
foreach (var post in posts.Value)
{
    var likers = await api.GetMediaLikersAsync(post.InstaIdentifier);
    foreach (var liker in likers.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(liker.UserName);
    }
}
```

This works fine for me, try it out, Im sure it will work for you as well.

Comment: this method return maximum 998 likers username  for me. is it pagination for likers too?!